# Select character columns in R which are numbers

Tags: r, dataframe

I have dataset which contains multiple numeric and character columns (more than 1000 columns), I want to identify only character variables which could be transformed into numeric variables.
Example:

```
> Df
  ID var0 var1 var2  var3
1  1   10   1A    a 500.2
2  2    8    2    b   400
3  3    9    7    c 603.1
4  4    2 aa4e    d   700
> str(Df)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ ID  : chr  "1" "2" "3" "4"
 $ var0: num  10 8 9 2
 $ var1: chr  "1A" "2" "7" "aa4e"
 $ var2: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d"
 $ var3: chr  "500.2" "400" "603.1" "700"
```

The required columns here are: ID and var3

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe `sapply(Df, function(x) all(!is.na(as.numeric(x))))` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `grepl` in `sapply` not testing if there are two `.`.

```
sapply(Df, function(x) !any(grepl("[^0-9.]", x)))
#   ID  var0  var1  var2  var3 
# TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

or:

```
sapply(Df, function(x) all(!is.na(as.numeric(x))))
#   ID  var0  var1  var2  var3 
# TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `type.convert` with `select`

```
library(dplyr)
Df %>%
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
    select(where(is.numeric))
```

-output

```
#   ID var0  var3
#1  1   10 500.2
#2  2    8 400.0
#3  3    9 603.1
#4  4    2 700.0
```

---

Or to select a column with any numeric part

```
library(stringr)
Df %>%
    select(where(~ any(str_detect(., '^[0-9]+$'))))
```

#### data

```
Df <- structure(list(ID = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), var0 = c(10L, 8L, 
9L, 2L), var1 = c("1A", "2", "7", "aa4e"), var2 = c("a", "b", 
"c", "d"), var3 = c("500.2", "400", "603.1", "700")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this regex solution :

```
names(Filter(function(x) is.character(x) && all(grepl('^\\d+\\.\\d+$', x)), Df))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R option using `Filter` + `is.numeric` + `type.convert`

```
> Filter(is.numeric, type.convert(Df, as.is = TRUE))
  ID var0  var3
1  1   10 500.2
2  2    8 400.0
3  3    9 603.1
4  4    2 700.0
```